# Symfony make:entity fails

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I have a problem creating entity on Symfony 6.4. When I try to `symfony console make:entity` it fails because:

```
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Academy-ERP>php bin/console make:entity

 ! [NOTE] It looks like your app may be using a namespace other than "App".
 !
 !        To configure this and make your life easier, see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html#configuration

 Class name of the entity to create or update (e.g. OrangePopsicle):
 > Orange

[critical] Error thrown while running command "make:entity". Message: "Could not determine where to locate the new class "App\Entity\Orange", maybe try with a full namespace like "\My\Full\Namespace\Orange""

In Generator.php line 63:

  Could not determine where to locate the new class "App\Entity\Orange", maybe try with a full namespace like "\My\Full\Namespace\Orange"
```

Tried all internet solutions. Didn't work.
I need to work with this version of Symfony. I can't upgrade it with latest.

Composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "invertus/academy",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "description": "A minimal Symfony project recommended to create bare bones applications",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1.7",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.17",
        "runtime/frankenphp-symfony": "^0.2.0",
        "symfony/console": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php82": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.4.*",
            "docker": true
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.52"
    }
}
```

I tried intalling orm-pack, doctrine-bundle, changing namespace in composer.json and kernel.php

Comment: And, just to be clear, you didn’t change the default namespace of `App`, right?

Comment: Before that, it was not App, but after changing it to App didint work either

Comment: Are you starting from scratch, or working on an existing project?

Comment: Working on existing project, but nothing big was done. It was downgraded manually from 7 to 6.4

Comment: So it was both downgraded from 7 to 6.4 and re-namespaced? And for the latter, all of your existing files in `src` were edited to change their namespace, all `use` statements were updated, all references in YAML were changed, the maker bundle’s `root_namespace` value was changed, composer was updated, the cache cleared, and the system was working and passing all tests before you tried adding a new entity?

Comment: I get it after downgrading

Comment: So after downgrading and clearing the cache, did your application work perfectly still, and any tests you had had passed? There’s no “downgrade” documentation from Symfony (as far as I know), so this isn’t fully supported and I’m just checking to determine what specific step stopped this from working.

Comment: It was downgraded by other developer. After I cloned it, I cant create entity

Comment: I’m sorry if I sound like a broken record, but as “downgrade” isn’t an official thing, have you confirmed that it was successful?

Comment: I mean, other developer changed versions of symfony etc. in composer.json file and uploaded

Comment: Okay, so my problem is I need to change namespace to "App". What should I do to set it to "App" correctly?

Comment: This is probably my last try, I’m not sure if I’m communicating effectively. Just saying that the “other developer changed versions…” doesn’t answer my question. I’m not concerned in any way who did what. My question is, after the “downgrade” was performed, was the application fully tested, including all paths and possible unit tests. If you had any recipes, were those probably “downgraded” as well? You are stating that “event A” happened, and you have “problem B”. I’m trying to understand if “A” was successful before moving on to “B”.

Comment: I think it was not tested.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix was changing namespace in all files to default "App". Link that helped my change all namespaces. I will try to show as clearly as possible:

1. Update `composer.json`:

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      /* "Some\\Name\\": "src/"  remove this */
      "App\\": "src/" /* add this */
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
     /* "Some\\Name\\Tests\\": "tests/" remove this */
     "App\\Tests\\": "tests/" /* add this */
    }
  }

}
```

2. Edit `/src/Kernel.php` file:

```
// namespace Some\Name; remove this
namespace App; // add this

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;
}
```

3. Edit `bin/console` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// use Some\Name\Kernel; remove this
use App\Kernel; // add this

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;

if (!is_file(dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php')) {
    throw new LogicException('Symfony Runtime is missing. Try running "composer require symfony/runtime".');
}

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    $kernel = new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);

    return new Application($kernel);
};
```

4. Edit `/public/index.php`:

```
// use Some\Name\Kernel; remove this
use App\Kernel; // add this

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    return new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);
};
```

5. Edit `/config/services.yaml`:

```
/* Some\Name\: remove */
App\: /* add */
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
```

6. Edit `/config/preload.php` (may not be necessary because it will be correct):

```
<?php
// In if statement after __DIR__ preload file name before dot should be App_.....
// Also in require should be the same
if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php')) {
    require dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php';
}
```

6. Edit `/config/doctrine.yaml` (in older symfony versions), in latest versions `/config/packages/doctrine.yaml`:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    # dbal specific configuration
  orm:
    # orm specific configuration
    mappings:
      /* Cspray\MyCoolApp: remove */
         App: /* add */
          is_bundle: false
          type: annotation
          dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
          /* prefix: 'Some\Name\Entity' remove */
          prefix: App\Entity' /* add */
          alias: App
```

7. Edit `/bin/dev/maker.yaml`. If you don't have folder `/dev/` and file `maker.yaml` **create it and write this**:

```
maker:
  root_namespace: 'App'
```

[Reference](https://www.cspray.io/blog/customize-symfony-namespaces/)